# Iterating over the named and unnamed elements separately in an R list

Tags: r, list, loops, named

In R, I have a list that contains both named elements and unnamed elements. I want to iterate over the whole list and apply a function that only takes the element for unnamed elements and apply a different function to both the name and the attached elements for named elements.

In pseudo code, the function would look something like `if(named) f(name, list[[name]]) else g(element)`, where `list[[name]]` is the element stored with that name.

For example, if the list element is unnamed then the element is returned. If the list element is named, then I want to return the name repeated a number of times equal to the element (assume that the element is an integer).

If I had `ll = list(a = 5, b = 3, 9, 18)` then the function should return a a list with elements

```
[[1]]
[1] "aaaaa"

[[2]]
[1] "bbb"

[[3]]
[1] 9

[[4]]
[1] 18
```

I thought about iterating over `names(ll)` but this cannot access the unnamed elements. Both `names[[3]]` and `names[[4]]` are equal to `""` and `ll[[""]] = NULL`.

The process doesn't need to be very efficient so I could use

```
for(i in 1:length(names(ll)))
  if(names(ll)[[i]] == "")
    g(ll[[i]])
  else
    f(names(ll)[[i]], ll[[names(ll)[[i]])
```

but I was looking for a neater solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ll = list(a = 5, b = 3, 9, 18)

lapply(seq_along(ll), function(x){
         if(names(ll[x]) == ""){
            ll[[x]]
         }else{
            paste0(rep(names(ll[x]), times =ll[[x]]), collapse = '')
         }
            }
      )

[[1]]
[1] "aaaaa"

[[2]]
[1] "bbb"

[[3]]
[1] 9

[[4]]
[1] 18
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a little named function

```
named<-function(x) names(x)!=''
```

and then use it on your list:

```
ll <- list(a = 5, b = 3, 9, 18)
ll[named(ll)]
# $a
# [1] 5
# 
# $b
# [1] 3
```

Or the other way:

```
ll[!named(ll)]
# [[1]]
# [1] 9
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 18
```

But this will fail if you have no names on the list at all, so you could modify `named` to handle that case:

```
named<-function(x) if (is.null(names(x))) rep(FALSE,length(x)) else names(x)!=''
```